# FCGI perl script ceases to respond on requests

Tags: perl, signals, alarm, fastcgi

I have this code (server.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FCGI;
use POSIX qw(:signal_h);
use Time::HiRes qw(alarm);

my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket(":9010", 10000);
my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket, FCGI::FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR);

my $old_sigaction = POSIX::SigAction->new;
my $sigaction = POSIX::SigAction->new('sig_alarm', undef, POSIX::SA_RESTART);
POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, $sigaction, $old_sigaction) or die "can't sigaction: $!";

sub sig_alarm {
    print "alarm " . rand() . "\n";
    alarm(0.01);
} 
alarm(0.01);
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n1\n";
}
```

This is a FCGI server. It listens port 9010. It has one thread. The server prints on the screen a random text every 10 milliseconds.

Nginx passes requests to this server.

A part of nginx's config:

```
location /counter/ {

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9010;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I start server.pl:

```
$ ~/server.pl 
alarm 0.309887429307313
alarm 0.0700285703382804
alarm 0.524615473850769
alarm 0.518569373615669
...
```

Server.pl is printing text on the screen.

Then I launch this command:

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/ab -k -c 80 -t 300 http://127.0.0.1/counter/
```

Sometimes server.pl ceases to respond on requests.
strace for server.pl displays this:

```
futex(0x7f5035818e80, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

Why this happend?

Comment: Maybe the single thread has issues answering 80 concurrent requests?

Comment: No.  $ ab -c 1 -t 300 -k http://127.0.0.1/counter/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 15000 requests
!!!BLOCKING!!!
^C

Comment: Is it always stopping to work after the same number of requests (15000..20000)? Maybe a limit is reached?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem but with other signals. The reason lies in the fact that you use SA_RESTART POSIX signal handlers and is not even related to perl. It all depends on what calls you use in the alarm sub. In my case it's localtime() (but via Sys::Syslog) which isn't on the safe list and hence need to set a fast user lock (futex).

You can read about that [here](http://blogs.inxsasia.com/hiran/2009/07/stupid-futex-and-glibc.html)

I have yet to find a good solution. regular perl signal handling is ok, but without SA_RESTART, a lot of libraries that do I/O like oracle DB libraries will exit their calls "at random".

If you can go without SA_RESTART and POSIX handlers, just use %SIG - what might not be even possible in FCGI.